# Pandas Python - Transform a list-of-list column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to transform this DF

```
pd.DataFrame({"l1": [["fr en","en"]],
              "l2": [["fr en","in","it"]],
              "l3": [["he","es","fi"]],
              "l4": [["es"]]}).T
>> l1  [fr en, en]
   ...
   l4  [es]
```

to this DTM :

```
data = [[1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,1,1]]
pd.DataFrame(index=["l1","l2","l3","l4"], data=data, columns=["fr en","en","in","it","he","es","fi"])
>>      fr en en in it he es fi
    l1  1     1  0  0  0  0  0
    ... ...
```

My inefficient way to do this is to `chain` all possible values then to Count-Vectorize like

```
langs = set(chain(*df["lang"]))
pd.DataFrame(data=df["lang"].apply(lambda x: [1 if lang in x else 0 for lang in langs]).tolist(), columns=langs)
```

PS : I don't want to `" ".join()` the lists because it could represent a loss of information as you can see in `fr en`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[0]),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
print (df)
    en  es  fi  fr en  he  in  it
l1   1   0   0      1   0   0   0
l2   0   0   0      1   0   1   1
l3   0   1   1      0   1   0   0
l4   0   1   0      0   0   0   0
```

Or is possible use slowier solution with join by `|` if this separator not exist in data:

```
df = df[0].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
print (df)
    en  es  fi  fr en  he  in  it
l1   1   0   0      1   0   0   0
l2   0   0   0      1   0   1   1
l3   0   1   1      0   1   0   0
l4   0   1   0      0   0   0   0
```

Comment: excellent I did not even think about the `MultiLabelBinarizer`